# Adding additional files file into Python executable

Tags: python, exe, autopy

I have a script that invokes Selenium and files in values from a selected CSV. I've used PyGUI as the interface. Now I'd like to convert the script into an executable but I also need to add the chromedriver.exe file bundled with it, how do I go about this ? I've tried auto-py-to-exe one file and added the additional file but nothing happens after I launch the app and submit, in which case it needs to launch Chrome and feed values from the CSV. I need to be able to bundle the chromedriver.exe into this program.
In folder mode its working perfectly, need to just make it into one-file.
My program:

```
import csv
import time
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
import PySimpleGUI as sg



def make_window(theme):

    sg.theme(theme)
    menu_def = [['&Application', ['E&xit']],
                ['&Help', ['&About']] ]
    right_click_menu_def = [[], ['Exit']]

    # Table Data


    input_layout =  [[sg.Menu(menu_def, key='-MENU-')],
                 
                
                [sg.Button("Open File")],
               
                [sg.Text('Chrome Version')],

                [sg.OptionMenu(values=('96', '97', '98'),  k='-OPTION MENU-'),],
               
                [sg.Button('Submit')]]



    
    
    layout = [[sg.Text('Email Automation', size=(38, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 16), relief=sg.RELIEF_RIDGE, k='-TEXT HEADING-', enable_events=True)]]
    layout +=[[sg.TabGroup([[  sg.Tab('Setup CSV and Chrome Version', input_layout),
                               
                               ]], key='-TAB GROUP-')]]
              
    return sg.Window('', layout, right_click_menu=right_click_menu_def)


def main():
    window = make_window(sg.theme())
    
    # This is an Event Loop 
    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
        # keep an animation running so show things are happening
       
        if event not in (sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT, sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            print('============ Event = ', event, ' ==============')
            print('-------- Values Dictionary (key=value) --------')
            for key in values:
                print(key, ' = ',values[key])
        if event in (None, 'Exit'):
            print("[LOG] Clicked Exit!")
            break
        elif event == 'About':
            print("[LOG] Clicked About!")
            sg.popup('Aucor email automation',
                     'Select CSV file',
                     'Select Chrome Version',
                     'Submit',
                     'Powered By ')
        elif event == 'Popup':
            print("[LOG] Clicked Popup Button!")
            sg.popup("You pressed a button!")
            print("[LOG] Dismissing Popup!")


        elif event == "Open File":
            print("[LOG] Clicked Open File!")
            csv_file_selected = sg.popup_get_file('Choose your file')
            sg.popup("You chose: " + str(folder_or_file))
            print("[LOG] User chose file: " + str(folder_or_file))




def run_selenium(window, file, driver):

    with open(file, 'rt') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Web Automation
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver)
    driver.get('')
  
    
    fname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FIRSTNAME"]')
    lname_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="LASTNAME"]')
    phone_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PHONE"]')
    mail_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="EMAIL"]')
    deposit_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="DEPOSIT"]')
    submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sib-form"]/div[8]/div/button')

    with open(file, 'rt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        next(csv_reader)
        for line in csv_reader:
            
            time.sleep(2.5)
            
            fname_field.send_keys(line[10])
            lname_field.send_keys(line[11])
            mail_field.send_keys(line[13])
            phone_field.send_keys(line[16])
            deposit_field.send_keys(line[37])
            submit.click()

    # Not to update GUI in thread, but generate an event which will be processed in event loop.
    window.write_event_value('Done', None)

def main():
    # My GUI
    window = make_window(sg.theme())
    folder_or_file = None
    # Using your path for all the drivers of all versions
    paths = {
        #'96': './chromedriver.exe',
        '96': '.chromedriver.exe',
        
    }

    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
        # keep an animation running so show things are happening

        if event not in (sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT, sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            # print('============ Event = ', event, ' ==============')
            # print('-------- Values Dictionary (key=value) --------')
            for key in values:
               # print(key, ' = ',values[key])
        if event in (None, 'Exit'):
           # print("[LOG] Clicked Exit!")
            break
        elif event == 'About':
           # print("[LOG] Clicked About!")
            sg.popup('email',
                     'Select CSV file',
                     'Select Chrome Version',
                     'Submit',
                     '')
        elif event == 'Popup':
           # print("[LOG] Clicked Popup Button!")
            sg.popup("You pressed a button!")
           # print("[LOG] Dismissing Popup!")
        elif event == "Open File":
            #print("[LOG] Clicked Open File!")
            folder_or_file = sg.popup_get_file('Choose your file')
            # sg.popup("You chose: " + str(folder_or_file))
            #print("[LOG] User chose file: " + str(folder_or_file))
        elif event == 'Submit':
            version = values['-OPTION MENU-']
            if folder_or_file is None or version not in paths:
              #  print("No CSV file selected or wrong Chrome version selected")
                continue
            # Using thread to avoid long time job will block and cause GUI no response
            threading.Thread(target=run_selenium, args=(window, folder_or_file, paths[version])).start()
            # Disable Submit button to prevent submit again when threading
            window['Submit'].update(disabled=True)
          #  print('[LOG] Run Selenium ...')
        elif event == 'Done':
            # Enable Submit button when thread done
            window['Submit'].update(disabled=False)
           # print('[LOG] End Selenium')

    window.close()

main()
```

However I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You're referencing a file that's in the same folder as the program - bundling everything up or not, if that file doesn't exist that will always throw an error. How large is the file? Maybe you can store the binary in a py file as a string/array and then recreate the file when you start your program.

Comment: Its around 10mb, running it without onefile it runs perfect from the folder. I've tried . ,./ ,/ for the file and added the def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
 
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path) function from another post

Comment: have you checked that the file is actually in the temp folder?

Comment: In the folder option the file is there and the app runs perfect executing from the folder ,only single file is giving me the issue of it not finding the file

Comment: Try running `psgcompiler`.  It's a new front-end to PyInstaller.  It makes getting to the options easier.  you can pip install it and there's also a repo for it.

Answer (score 0):

Added all files into a folder and added it as a path along with adding the additional file and boom it worked